# RInside linking on mac osx

Tags: macos, r, rinside

Hi i'm trying to compile and run simple RInside examples on mac osx. I'm using R installed form macports and RInside installed via R as well with the latest release of all libraries
heres my R information

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
```

heres how I try to compile an example

```
 g++-mp-4.7 -I/opt/local/lib/R/library/RInside/include/
    -I/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/ -I/opt/local/lib/R/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/R/library/RInside/libs/ -L/opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/libs/ -lRInside -lRcpp test.cpp -o test
```

and heres my error

```
In file included from /opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:155:0,
                 from /opt/local/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from /opt/local/lib/R/library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:31,
                 from /opt/local/lib/R/library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
                 from thread_safe_test.cpp:5:
/opt/local/lib/R/include/R.h:34:21: fatal error: Rconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, you maty have to compile RInside from source on OS X.  Try the archives of the rcpp-devel list for more.

Comment: i will take your word for it and just delete the mac ports version

Comment: One of the key issues is ... that the path from compile time gets hard code so if your layout of directories is different than the build box, it will fail -- often the case on Windows, and possibly here too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So do we need to download RInside for OSX or Rcpp for OSX or both?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the version from [r-project.org](http://www.r-project.org) and download the compilers etc. from http://r.research.att.com/tools/? That's the preferred method I think. For me this approach works.